# Parsley JS Add Error/Success Class to Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm using Parsley JS (http://parsleyjs.org/) for form validation. The default behavior for errors is to add a class of `parsley-error` to each invalid input. However, I'd like to change up the default behavior and add the error class to the parent of the input - specifically on the `form-group` element.

The basic HTML

```
<form class="js-contact-form">

  <!-- this field is just required, it would be validated on form submit -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" required />
  </div>

  <!-- this required field must be an email, and validation will be run on field change -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email * :</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" />
  </div>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm using the "Javascript Installation" to initialize everything and I tried overriding the "errorClass" and "successClass" options with my own function, but doesn't seem to work.

```
 $('.js-contact-form').parsley({
    trigger:      'change',
    errorClass:   function(){
      $(this).parent()
           .removeClass('has-success')
           .addClass('has-error has-feedback');
    },
    successClass: function(){
      $(this).parent()
           .removeClass('has-error')
           .addClass('has-success has-feedback');
    },
    errorsWrapper: '<div class="invalid-message"></div>',
    errorTemplate: '<span></span>',
});
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
  <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Name" required />
  <div class="invalid-message">
     <span>This field is required</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

You should use `classHandler` instead of `errorClass`.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-contact-form').parsley({
        trigger:      'change',
        successClass: "has-success",
        errorClass: "has-error",
        classHandler: function (el) {
            return el.$element.closest('.form-group'); //working
        },
        errorsWrapper: '<div class="invalid-message"></div>',
        errorTemplate: '<span></span>',
    });
});
```

You can also check this related answer here on SO: [parsley 2.0.3 not working with boostrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974417/parsley-2-0-3-not-working-with-boostrap-3/24974814#24974814)