# What Parsely configuration options set the CSS classes for error/success?

Tags: javascript, css, parsley.js

I'd like to add my own CSS class to the input fields, or associated elements, on validation failure or success. For example to facilate testing I'd like to add a `"qa-val-fail"` CSS class for detection by Selenium. Ideally I'd like to add multiple classes.

In the [Parsley documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-classes) it says:

> Customize your classes
>
> You could change these classes' names in
> configuration, and the class holder element too.

but there is no further mention in the documentation of which configuration settings achieve this.

I have seen a few SOs with techniques using event listeners, but I'm hoping not to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [doc of the defaults](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html), you'll find `successClass` and `errorClass`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame there isn't a definitive list of configuration options, they're scattered about in various places.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610173/209288

And this allows me to add multiple classes:

```
$(selector).parsley({
            successClass: "qa-validation-success parsley-success",
            errorClass: "qa-validation-error parsley-error"
  });
```